# CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications(); throwing NullReference iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuget-package

to do push notifications in my Xamarin Forms App, I am using the CrossGeeks FirebasePushNotification Plugin. My android setup is working alright, but for the iOS app, when I try to run the app, the line

`CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();`

is causing a NullReference Exception.  What I have done to set up:

- Set "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to "No"
- Changed the GoogleService plist to Bundle Resource
- Added the `FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);` in the App Delegate (and it is saying it is unreachable?"
- I am **testing on a simulator** but I believe this should only prevent the receiving of notifications, not the registering?

How would I solve this problem?  In the documentation, it states that these are the steps needed for iOS setup.

Comment: Have you added the 'notification capability' in Entitlement.plist? Can you check this answer? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181961/push-notification-plugin-for-xamarin-ios-and-android-not-working-on-ios

Comment: Yes, I added the notification capability.  Still says Object Reference not Set To Instance of an Object